# fade in a div on mousemove in another div, unless the fading div has display none set

Tags: jquery, css, html

does anyone know how to fade in a div on mousemove in another div, Unless the fading div is set to display none? display none will be triggered from another div on click.
Thanks.

Comment: You should first attempt to solve the problem, then ask a question when you hit a roadblock.  Posting the code you're working with is also a requirement.

Comment: to answer your question: yes, a lot of people knows. If you want to know too, just help yourself by adding some code or telling us what you did

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a div is visible by using the [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function.

```
$('#myDiv').is(':visible');
```

http://api.jquery.com/is/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="content" style="display:block">
    some content
</div>

<div id="one">
    another content
</div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $('#one').mousemove(function(){
            if($('#content').css('display') != 'none'){
                $('#content').fadeOut();
            }       
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Based on what I understood from your requirement, I came up with the sample code and provided the solution here.

When you move your mouse on the second div (id=one), the first div will fade out. Hope this is the one you expected!